# Parse.com - Retrieving image URL when templating a collection in JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, parse-platform

I am uploading an image with the JS SDK which is working fine.

When i need to display the image in a templated view I can use the following code which is working for me:

var img = user.get('profileimage').url();

But how about when i need to display the image from a collection?

So I display a list of users associated with another user account who have a profile image. But there does not seem to be a clear way to get this URL from the collection as I cannot call methods on the object from the template?

I tried templating out this attribute but it still does not give me the image:

user.attributes.profileImage._url

Answer (score 0):

Then dont call the object from template.

Rather, in your process, you should be able to iterate the collection and then call a template for each  $User in the collection.

You will have a template that just handles one user/profile/pic at a time. Above that is an iterator on the collection.

To see sample code look for ['sample todo app'](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Todo/blob/master/js/todos.js) where you will see code like below:

```
   // Add a single todo item to the list by creating a view for it, and
    // appending its element to the `<ul>`.
    addOne: function(todo) {
      var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
      this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
    },

    // Add all items in the Todos collection at once.
    addAll: function(collection, filter) {
      this.$("#todo-list").html("");
      this.todos.each(this.addOne);
    },
```